# What variable types I should NOT use in iPhone code?

Tags: iphone, performance, types

Can't find it now, but I recall I should avoid using **double** variables in iPhone coding for (poor) performance reasons? Is this true? Are there any other known problems with some variable types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `float` or `double` on embedded devices is slow when there is no FPU.

About floating point performance on the iPhone, you can have a look at [Break That Thumb For Best iPhone Performance](http://gamesfromwithin.com/break-that-thumb-for-best-iphone-performance) and [Cranking Up Floating Point Performance To 11](http://gamesfromwithin.com/360idev-cranking-up-floating-point-performance-to-11): it deals with floating point performance and floating point operations causing the program to switch back and forth between Thumb mode and regular 32-bit mode.

See also [Squeezing Every Drop Of Performance Out Of The iPhone](http://gamesfromwithin.com/gdc-austin-2009-squeezing-every-drop-of-performance-out-of-the-iphone).